# Pandas merge datagrames based on most similar values

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am attempting to Merge 2 pandas dataframes, however, the values are not exactly the same in the merge columns.

I am using the command 
`pd.merge(D_data, L_data,on="R_Time")`
however, in D_data my R_time Column looks like

`4.316667, 4.320834,    4.325000`

 
and in my L_data column my data looks like:

`4.31000, 4.32000, ...`

Essentially, what I am trying to do is take every item in the first set, and match it to the closest element in the second set. I've done this with the vlookup function in Excel, but I'm not entire sure how to get the same functionality in Pandas Dataframe objects.

Given Data:

`D_data:

4.316667

4.320834
4.325
4.329167
4.333334
4.3375
4.341667
4.345834
4.35
4.354167
4.358334`

`L_Data 
4.316667
4.318667
4.320667
4.322667
4.324667
4.326667
4.328667
4.330667
4.332667
4.334667
4.336667`

I Want to produce a pairing between exactly these elements, even though they are not exactly identical in most cases.

Comment: Can you gives us some data to work with?  Both input and expected output?

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Pandas' `merge_asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

Answer (score 1):

First create a column in L_data with the value from R_data that is closest (index of smallest absolute difference) and then merge:

```
import pandas as pd
D_data =pd.DataFrame({"R_Time":[4.316667,4.320834,4.325,4.329167,4.333334,4.3375,4.341667,4.345834,4.35,4.354167,4.358334]})
L_data =pd.DataFrame({"_R_Time":[4.316667,4.318667,4.320667,4.322667,4.324667,4.326667,4.328667,4.330667,4.332667,4.334667,4.336667]})

L_data["R_Time"]=L_data.apply(lambda x:D_data["R_Time"][abs(D_data["R_Time"]-x["_R_Time"]).idxmin()],axis=1)
pd.merge(D_data, L_data,on="R_Time")
```

Result:

```
      R_Time   _R_Time
0   4.316667  4.316667
1   4.316667  4.318667
2   4.320834  4.320667
3   4.320834  4.322667
4   4.325000  4.324667
5   4.325000  4.326667
6   4.329167  4.328667
7   4.329167  4.330667
8   4.333334  4.332667
9   4.333334  4.334667
10  4.337500  4.336667
```